# Get breakdown from de-normalized SQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given this kind of de-normalized table:

```
SUB_LOCATION, LOCATION, LOCATION_STATUS 
A_1, A, GOOD
A_2, A, GOOD
B_1, B, BAD
B_2, B, BAD
B_3, B, BAD
C_1, C, EXCELLENT
D_1, D, EXCELLENT
D_2, D, EXCELLENT
E_1, E, BAD
F_1, F, BAD
```

How do I get a breakdown for the number of each kind of location_status by location?

Meaning that multiple sub_locations with the same location/location_status pair should be counted as 1 regarding the location_status count, like this:

```
BAD, 3
EXCELLENT, 2
GOOD, 1
```

Here BAD is 3 because it appears in B, E and F locations, and EXCELLENT is 2 because it appears in C and D, etc.

I found several work-around ways, but I want the fastest way to do this in Postgres, perhaps involving PARTITION BY. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the distinct appearances of location for each status.

```
   SELECT location_status, 
          COUNT(DISTINCT(location))
     FROM table
 GROUP BY location_status
```

Comment: This would be the standard way to do it. Not sure what "work-arounds" the original poster was using.

Comment: Didn't occur to me that you can combine COUNT and DISTINCT this way. Rusty SQL...